# Performing a Click on div Elements

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to click a div element with protractor, but it is giving me an error saying "Element not interactable." This is a menu and when you click one of the div another menu is supposed to pop up.

```
    <div class="col">

        <div class="games">

                <div class="game" rel="board">
                    Chess
                </div>

                <div class="game" rel="sports">
                    Basketball
                </div>

                <div class="game" rel="active">
                    Exercise
                </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

What I tried is

```
    element.all(by.cssContainingText('.game','Exercise')).click();
    element(by.cssContainingText('.game','Chess')).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
element.all(by.cssContainingText('.game','Exercise')).click();
browser.wait(ExpectedCondition.elementToBeClickable(element(by.cssContainingText('.game','Chess')),60000,'Wait for the element to become clickable'));
element(by.cssContainingText('.game','Chess')).click();
```

If this does not help try adding `browser.sleep()` before trying to access the element.

Answer (score 0):

JS click

```
export async function jsClickButton(button: ElementFinder) {

    try {
        return await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', button).then(async() => {
            console.log('Element has been clicked.');
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Element could not be clicked', error);
    }
}
```